# How do I round columns based on heading type

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table consisting of strings and numbers.  Row one contains the heading and row two contains the unit type (percent and dollars).  I would like to round the numbers in the column based on the heading in row two.

At the moment I am selecting the columns individually.  Is there a way to round the column based on the heading in row two?

```
Sub Round()

Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Determine 
last row

        For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("R3:R" & Lastrow)
        cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Round(cell.Value, 2) 'Round dollars to 2 places
        Next cell

        For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("AB3:AB" & Lastrow)
        cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Round(cell.Value, 2)
        Next cell

       For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("Q3:Q" & Lastrow)
       cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Round(cell.Value, 1) 'Round percentages to 1 places
       Next cell

       ....

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close enough, just needed a bit from both of those tries together. Please see if the below helps, I've added an alternative using arrays as well (if you have lots of data, it will be much faster):

```vb
Sub RoundRanges()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet 'better use something like: ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet name here")
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row
Dim lCol As Long: lCol = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'get last column

Dim R As Long, C As Long

For C = 1 To lCol 'iterate through each column
    Select Case ws.Cells(2, C) 'get the text of the cell 2...
        Case "Percent"
            For R = 3 To lRow 'iterate through each row
                ws.Cells(R, C) = WorksheetFunction.Round(ws.Cells(R, C).Value, 1) 'apply the desired calculation
            Next R
        Case "Dollars"
            For R = 3 To lRow 'iterate through each row
                ws.Cells(R, C) = WorksheetFunction.Round(ws.Cells(R, C).Value, 2) 'apply the desired calculation
            Next R
    End Select
Next C

'ALTERNATIVE:
'Dim arrData As Variant: arrData = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lRow, lCol))
'For R = LBound(arrData) + 2 To UBound(arrData) 'skip first 2 rows
'    For C = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
'        If arrData(2, C) = "Percent" Then
'            arrData(R, C) = Round(arrData(R, C), 1)
'        ElseIf arrData(2, C) = "Dollars" Then
'            arrData(R, C) = Round(arrData(R, C), 2)
'        End If
'    Next C
'Next R
'ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lRow, lCol)) = arrData

End Sub
```